# Jquery Ajax to [WebMethod]

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm posting the following to an asp.net [Webmethod] using jquery via the $.ajax method. I've trapped the data being sent over the wire.

{number:01502,numberTypeId:2,companyId:531}

I've break pointed inside the [Webmethod] and the number is being returned as 1502 even though the parameter type is string, I'm guessing this has something to do with the deserialisation.

Can anyone shed any light. ( I've tried wrapping it in quotes before transmission )

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSON serialization, strings need to be delimited with double quotes:

```
{number:"01502",numberTypeId:2,companyId:531}
```

That's the issue.

Comment: No worries. I answered before I read that you'd tried quotes, but presumably they had been single ones?